# JS Date conversion

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert Date using Javascript Date() method. But getting NaN when trying to parse it.
Below is the code I am trying with.

```
let tmp="29/02/2020 15:27:32"
console.log(Date.parse(tmp));
```

Comment: This is a non-standard date string, so I wouldn't rely on it being parsed correctly or at all.

Comment: Also relevant: [Converting a string to a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5619202)

Comment: let tmp="2020-02-29 15:27:32";
    console.log(new Date(Date.parse(tmp)));

Comment: created a JSFiddle for your scenario to convert the string to Date format. https://jsfiddle.net/ge7tz0wm/